# Add White dots to login screen

Tags: login-screen

Some people may not like the white dots on login screen of ubuntu 12.10, But i really love it , is there any way to add these dots desktop also and is there any way to remove these from the desktop(after addition of the dots in desktop)??

Comment: have you thought about just adding that dots to picture, and than set that picture as login screen image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what you need, to add that 'dots' to picture you want, and after that just set that image as background image in login screen.
To do that I have googled some links:

- [How to change login screen background](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/10/change-ubuntu-12-10-login-screen-background/)
- [How to remove dots from background](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/remove-white-dots-from-login-screen-of.html)

From second link I guess this way must work.

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid true
```

This will may work too.